# How to convert viewer coordinates back to CAD coordinates?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to convert from the viewer (scene) coordinates back to the original CAD coordinates. I have seen people mentioning the global offset, but whenever I try to retrieve this, I get undefined. I assumed this means there is no offset. But when I compare two coordinates one in the viewer and one in CAD, they are definitely not equal. I came across the function `NOP_VIEWER.model.getUnitScale()`; however, this number did not seem to mean anything when applying it to the coordinates.

That being said, how can I convert back to the CAD coordinates from the viewer coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The `globalOffset` is for 3D model commonly with my experience, you can apply the `PageToModelTransform` to your viewer points to transform them back to CAD. The following code snippet is extracted from a demo called [viewer-dwgoffset](https://github.com/jaimerosales/viewer-dwgoffset/blob/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Viewer-Helpers.js) written by our colleague.

Its key concept is using the `VertexBufferReader` to read vertices of a Forge Viewer 2D model, and get the corresponding transformation matrix to project points of the Viewer back to DWG coordinate system.

```
function GeometryCallback(viewer) {
    this.viewer = viewer;
}

GeometryCallback.prototype.onLineSegment = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, vpId) {
    var vpXform = this.viewer.model.getPageToModelTransform(vpId);

    var pt1 = new THREE.Vector3().set(x1, y1, 0).applyMatrix4(vpXform);
    var pt2 = new THREE.Vector3().set(x2, y2, 0).applyMatrix4(vpXform);

    console.log('Line segment vertices in CAD coordinate system', {
        pointX1: pt1.x,
        pointY1: pt1.y,
        pointX2: pt2.x,
        pointY2: pt2.y
    });
}

GeometryCallback.prototype.onCircularArc = function(cx, cy, start, end, radius, vpId) {
};

GeometryCallback.prototype.onEllipticalArc = function(cx, cy, start, end, major, minor, tilt, vpId) {

};

var it = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
it.enumNodeFragments( dbId, function( fragId ) {
    var m = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer.model, fragId);
    var vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader(m.geometry, viewer.impl.use2dInstancing);
    vbr.enumGeomsForObject(dbId, new GeometryCallback());
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how do I get the position on the click on the canvas and convert that to cad coordinates ?